# Авторизация на сайте через cookie средствами Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookie, браузер, requests

Требуется написать скрипт для входа на сайт и дальнейшей работы на нем. На нем стоит защита от автоматических систем (https://binomo.com/ru НЕ РЕКЛАМА). Да и опыта у меня мало, написал пару скриптов для телеги, ВК и обработки видео. Но вот я подумал возможно ли вместо авторизации использовать cookie от браузера? Только как это сделать и проверить что работает? Нашел модуль browsercookie, но по нему мало примеров чтобы разобраться.
Пока имею следующее:

```
import browsercookie
import requests
cj = browsercookie.firefox()
r=requests.post('https://binomo.com/ru/trading', cookies=cj)
print(r.status_code)
```

выдает 500.
Помогите, пожалуйста, советом или ткните в путевый материал если есть такой.

Comment: Попробуйте Grab

Comment: Возможно, следует отправлять запрос методом get: 

requests.get('https://binomo.com/ru/trading', cookies=cj)